# Rewriting all request to index.php in the same diectory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want all the request to be rewrited to index.php so I used this htaccess code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

It works fine when site is hosted on home directory. But suppose if I move my site to a subdirectory `xyz` and move all my files including .htacess file inside this directory. Then if I access `http://example.com/xyz/some_page`, the request is not redirected to `/xyz/index.php`.

So, How can I make this rewrite work even on subdirectories as in my case.

Update:
I forgot to mention the directory `xyz` as in my case is likely to change frequently. So, this directory doesn't need to be hard coded in the rewrite rule

Comment: @AD7six Sorry, I am using this updated .htaccess rule. I posted the wrong one earlier

Comment: @AD7six The link you provided worked for me. Can you just explain the difference between these two lines. `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]` and `RewriteRule . index.php [L]`. BTW, Thanks for answer

Comment: They are basically the same. The first matches the start of the url (irrespective of what the url is) and rewrites to index.php; the second matches the first character of the url (irrespective of what that character is - it'll be '/') and rewrites to index.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Remove the RewriteBase

If you don't need the rewrite base - just remove it. A working example based on the one shown in the question would be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Note that the first rewrite rule has been deleted as it is logically equivalent to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` (do not rewrite requests for a file that exists).

Consider also deleting `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` as this prevents urls like `/this/folder/exists` being sent to index.php. Most relevant if [Directory listings are enabled](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings) but not desired.

Comment: I got one more similar question. ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22094515/rewrite-request-to-a-sub-directory Sorry, I am really very bad in htaccess

Answer (score 0):

change your base url for rewrite

```
RewriteBase subdir/
```

or try with full url

```
RewriteBase http://www.examle.com/subdir/
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention the directory xyz as in my case is likely to change frequently. So, this directory doesn't need to be hard coded in the rewrite rule