# Rewrite request to a sub directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a web application in a directory suppose `xyz`. I am trying to redirect all requests to a sub directory `www`. My current .htaccess code is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) /www/$1 [L]
```

But, when I visit `http://example.com/xyz/some_url` the request is redirected to `http://example.com/www/some_url` rather `http://example.com/xyz/www/some_url` which I want.

Update: Sorry, I forgot to mention the directory xyz as in my case is likely to renamed. So, this directory doesn't need to be hard coded in the rewrite rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this rule in `/xyz/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /xyz/

RewriteRule ^((?!www/).*)$ www/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Great this worked for me. After removing the second line. `RewriteBase /xyz/`

Answer (score 0):

If your DocumentRoot does not contain the `xyz` path then you'll need to specify in the RewriteRule.

E.g.: `RewriteRule (.*) /xyx/www/$1 [L]`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention the directory xyz as in my case is likely to renamed. So, this directory doesn't need to be hard coded in the rewrite rule

Comment: @VarunAgw Then I believe you'll need to make sure its part of the DocumentRoot

Comment: I don't got what you said. xyz is inside the document root and can be renamed by user

Comment: You may need to investigate further. For example, Wordpress solves this problem by allowing the .htaccess file containing Rewrites to be overwritten. Thus allowing the path to be changed and the rewrite to updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This should work or be close I think:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([^/]+)$ $1/www/$2 [L]
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention the directory xyz as in my case is likely to renamed. So, this directory doesn't need to be hard coded in the rewrite rule

Comment: I'm not sure what you would want the logic to be then, do you want to redirect anything from any subdirectory into subdirectory/www?

Comment: Redirect everything from http://example.com/x/y/z/some_url to  http://example.com/xyz/www/some_url. Where x,y,z can be any number of directories.

Comment: Sorry, not working at my side...rewriting `http://vk.eight/a/dsad` to `http://vk.eight/a/dsad` instead of `http://vk.eight/a/www/dsad`

Comment: Check your comment please, you put the same URL twice so not sure

Comment: Please try this version - moving the www to after the sub directories

Answer (score 0):

### Use a relative path and two .htaccess files

You need only remove the leading / to rewrite to a url relative to the current folder:

```
# /xyz/.htaccess
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    (.*) www/$1    [L]
```

This will rewrite `/xyz/foo` to `/xyz/www/foo`.

To prevent redirect loops add a `.htaccess` file to the `www` subfolder e.g.:

```
# /xyz/www/.htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Adjust as appropriate.